# How to build the sentence with degrees?

Tags: grammar

It is difficult for me to understand how to make the sentence with degree.
Please say if the following sentences I made are grammatically correct:

1. *She started talking with such a loud voice so that my ears began to ache.*
2. *She is drilling the wall with such a loud that the windows begin trembling.*
3. *She was studying such hard so that she was able to pass the exam.*
   (i.e. She studied hard and she passed the exam).

Answer (score 2):

Not the best question for this specific Stack Exchange.  It's probably better-suited to the English Grammar section, but I'll answer it anyway.

The typical form for this type of construction is as follows:

a) **so + ADJ/ADV that**

b) **such [a(n)] [ADJ] NOUN that**

This would render your sentences as follows:

1) She started talking with such a loud voice that my ears began to ache.

2) He is drilling the wall so loudly that the windows begin trembling.

3) She was studying so hard that she was able to pass the exam.

I will say that example sentence (2) is not the best, especially in the verb tense for the subordinate clause "...the windows begin trembling".  I think the phrase is stronger in the past tense:

"He **was** drilling the wall so hard that the windows **began** to tremble."

Whatever you choose, the SO/SUCH construction is the same.